# Cryptic Family Reunion: Fanfare for the Common Man

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are NOT sorted alphabetically. I hope you enjoy!

1. Brother's happy mate did a flip? (3)
2. Grandpa used to own a pier (7)
3. Nephew's metal infiltrates dormant party (7)
4. Auntie's unconstrained furniture style (4)
5. Dad feels one more audible will open middle for third-down run (8)
6. Mom lifting melon, removing rind (4)
7. Sister's iPhone to start location embedding (6)
8. Brother to stop drinking large quantity of IPAs? (7)
9. Spanish chicken? Spatchcock last pair for Madre (7)
10. Uncle to become full on stuffing, pork butt (5)

Comment: Oh man, #4 is brutal, no idea. Have everything but that and #5, where I only have a rough and probably incorrect answer ha.

Comment: For #4, it's probably good to remind you that I'm from the United States. If you're that far, perfectly OK to post a partial. And now I look at #5, I messed it up...let me fix.

Comment: @MrSethward: Mistake on my part...sorry about that. Please look at new clue for #5.

Answer (score 7):

Alright, think I've got them all, although still not certain on #3.

> All of the answers are types of white fish that are common in UK fish and chips, fanfare of the common man. (I find they often come with too little fish and too many chips, but it is delicious)

*1. Brother's happy mate did a flip? (3)*

> The dward Happy's mate DOC turned backwards is COD

*2. Grandpa used to own a pier (7)*

> HAD (used to own) + DOCK (pier) is HADDOCK

*3. Nephew's metal infiltrates dormant party (7)*

> Old political WHIG party from the US and UK that's no longer active, with TIN inside is WHITING

*4. Auntie's unconstrained furniture style (4)*

> TEAK, a type of wood common in furniture, anagrammed gives us KETA

*5. Dad feels one more audible will open middle for third-down run (8)*

> (F)eels + LOUDER with ruN in the middle is FLOUNDER.

> When the clue was "suggests one..." I had somehow gotten "suggests one more..." to mean URGES ON with audible being an anagram indicator (not crazy in terms of football reference I guess), with that becoming SURGEON. Then I was stuck explaining how I can add in a T to get STURGEON haha!

*6. Mom lifting melon, removing rind (4)*

> The cASABa melon backwards without the borders is BASA

*7. Sister's iPhone to start location embedding (6)*

> PLACE with an I inserted is PLAICE

*8. Brother to stop drinking large quantity of IPAs? (7)*

> HALT with IBU inserted is HALIBUT. IBU is the International Bittering Unit scale, something that IPAs score very high on due to their hops content!

*9. Spanish chicken? Spatchcock last pair for Madre (7)*

> POLLO, Spanish word for chicken, + spatchcoCK gives POLLOCK

*10.    Uncle to become full on stuffing, pork butt (5)*

> SATE, to become full inserted with the last letter of porK, gives SKATE

Comment: Almost all done! #4 is not what I had, and I think mine works a little better with the wordplay. Apologies on #5...the irony is that I had it correct, and "fixed" it in "quality control".

Comment: Also, can you be more specific on the topic, which might tie in with the title? (It's actually more a UK tie-in, to be honest.)

Comment: Tasty answer! I approve :-)

Comment: Not sure I'm getting #4 tonight since not my initial thought. Appreciate any help from others. rot13(V jnf guvaxvat hapbafgenvarq jnf na nantenz vaqvpngbe naq sheavgher fglyr qrsvavgvba, ohg pna'g svther vg bhg. Nyfb ybbxrq ng fglyr nf nantenz vaqvpngbe ohg fgvyy abguvat un!)

Comment: rot13(Vs pybfrg jrer sheavgher, pYBFRg (hapbafgenvarq gryyvat hf gb ybfr gur raqf) naq erneenatr gb FBYR), ohg qba'g guvax vg pna pbhag nf sheavgher.)